# Android AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver clarfications

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-context

I am trying to write an android application that will silence the phone at a certain time, and to do that I am using a combination of an `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceiver` as per [this tutorial](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129). I am using a separate class that will contain the method to set up an event using the `AlarmManager` so that I can use the method in more than one of my activities. The code for this class is as follows:

```
public class EventScheduler {

    public static void schedule(Event event) {
        Calendar start = event.getStartTime();
        Calendar end = event.getEndTime();
        String status = event.getStatus();

        Context ctx;

        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("start_time", start);
        intent.putExtra("end_time", end);
        intent.putExtra("status", status);

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast();
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemSerivce(ALARM_SERVICE);


    }

    public static void unschedule(Event event) {

    }
}
```

My first question is about initializing the intent object. Since this method is defined in a class that does not extend Activity it does not have a context (`ctx`), but this method will be used in classes that do extend Activity, so how would I get the context of those classes to use in the initialization of the intent?

My second question is about initializing the PendingIntent. `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` is supposed to take 4 parameters, so again how would I get the context of the class calling this method to use as the first parameter? Also in the documentation it says that the second parameter, the requestCode is not used, does that mean this can be `0`?

My third question is about initializing the AlarmManager. Again the `ALARM_SERVICE` field is from a context object, so what context object would I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your `Context` into each method (in your case, most likely your `Activity`):

```
public static void schedule(Context ctx, Event event) {
    // ...
}
public static void unschedule(Context ctx, Event event) {
    // ...
}
```

And yes, `requestCode` for `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` can always be zero.

Comment: Can I use the context that I pass in for every instance of a context in this method, it seems like in the tutorial they are using two different contexts, one is `ctx` and the other is the context of the class?

Comment: @azrosen92 - yes, any `Context` will do in the case of `AlarmManager` related activities. Generally, only creating UI components require a specific type of `Context` (which require a `Activity`). Here's a good read on what `Context` does what: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question on context, you should pass the `ApplicationContext` and not directly the `Activity` in case you need the context throughout the applications lifecycle. If you pass your `Activity`, the `GarbageCollector` can't remove it from memory when it's no longer needed, which can cause memory leaks. You can get the application context using `context.getApplicationContext()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, In my app I pass my activity context (via this) to the PendingIntent.getBroadcast used via AlarmManager.setRepeating ... Will this cause a memory leak?